# PHP XML Writer not generating xml if node name is same

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to generte xml data from Associate array.

My array is

```
$data = array(
    'item' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'bar1',
        'price' => '10',
        'description' => '',
        'image_link_small' => '',
        'image_link_big' => ''
    ),
    'item' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'bar2',
        'price' => '20',
        'description' => '',
        'image_link_small' => '',
        'image_link_big' => ''
    ),
    'item' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'bar3',
        'price' => '30',
        'description' => '',
        'image_link_small' => '',
        'image_link_big' => ''
    ),
    'item' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'bar4',
        'price' => '40',
        'description' => '',
        'image_link_small' => 'link1',
        'image_link_big' => 'link2'
    )
);
```

My php array to xml converter code is

```
public function convertArrayToXML($data, $rootElement = 'root', $startDoc = '1.0', $xml_encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        $xml = new XmlWriter();
        $xml->openMemory();
        $xml->startDocument($startDoc, $xml_encoding);
        $xml->startElement($rootElement);

        function write(XMLWriter $xml, $data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $xml->startElement($key);
                    write($xml, $value);
                    $xml->endElement();
                    continue;
                }
                $xml->writeElement($key, $value);
            }
        }

        write($xml, $data);

        $xml->endElement();
        return $xml->outputMemory(true);
    }
```

But it is giving me output xml only last node ...

```
<root>
<item>
<id>4</id>
<name>bar4</name>
<price>40</price>
<description/>
<image_link_small>link1</image_link_small>
<image_link_big>link2</image_link_big>
</item>
</root>
```

If i change the **item** in array to **item1, item2, item3, item4** it is giving me 
correct xml data. what might be the problem?

Thank You

Comment: The conversion to XML is doing exactly what it is supposed to do with the data you are giving it. Try dumping your array immediately after you have defined it. You will find that each element overwrites the element before it, since each element has the same name, leaving only the last element.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a XML writer problem. Try

`var_dump($data);`

You will see the problem. You can't have the same key several times in an PHP array.

Comment: then how can i achieve multiple item nodes in my xml data?

Comment: add another "dimension" to your array: `item'=>array(  array(id=>2,...), array(id=>3, ...) )`

Comment: Or maybe if you know this array has only items, just rename the array: $items => array(array('id' => 1...),...)

Answer (score 1):

In `$data` array key values are same, that's why first three values are overwritten by last value.try something like :

```
$data = array(
  'item1' => array(.....),
  'item2' => array(.....),
  'item2' => array(.....)
)
```